# Remembering Authorization

Tags: oauth-2.0, laravel-5.3

I'm playing around with the new [laravel/passport](https://github.com/laravel/passport) package, thinking about using this as a SSO service, and I have followed the video from the [laracast](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/13) (that link might not work if you do not have an account. If not, it just guides you through getting a sample project up). The site works as expected; I am able to authenticate a user from a client application, and execute calls against the api using the returned API token.

However, even though I have authorized the client to access the protected resources, everytime I log in to the client I have to re-authorize the client. In case what I am saying is not making sense, this is the flow:

1. Visit my-client.app

   Redirect to sso.app\oauth\authorization (Authorization Server) to get authorization_code

   Login to sso.app

   Authorize my-client.app to access sso.app resources

   Redirect to my-client.app with authorization_code

   Make POST request to sso.app\oauth\token with authorization_code to get token

   Make requests to sso.app protected resources using token

   Log Out of my-client.app

   Redirect to sso.app/logged-out (Page saying you logged out of my-client.app)

   Visit my-client.app

   Redirect to sso.app\oauth\authorization to get authorization_code

At this point, the client is already logged into `sso.app` and has already granted authorization for `my-client.app` to access `sso.app`'s protected resources. Currently, `sso.app` is asking me to again grant authorization before it will give me an `authorization_code`. What I would like is for `sso.app` to realize that authorization has already been granted for the client by the user, so it should just issue an `authorization_code` without requesting for authorization again.

As an example, I am using Google to sign into SO, but I am not being asked for authorization every time.

EDIT:

It seems that what I am wanting to do `laravel/passport` cannot do out of the box.

An idea that I have is to create a table `client_user_authorizations` that will track what users have authorized what client. I will then add a trigger (I would rather tie into the `completeAuthorizationRequest` method on the class extending `GrantTypeInterface` for the `Authorization Grant`, but that seems like a major pain) to the `oauth_auth_codes` table that will insert to `client_user_authorizations` table on insert.

I would then make my own controller in place of passport's `AuthorizationController` (handles `GET:/oauth/authorization`) that will call a method to see if the resource owner has already authorized the client and call the necessary methods to issue the `authorization_code` if that is the case. Otherwise, the current flow will occur.

What issues can you see with what I am thinking of doing?